# is the CollabNet SVN Server as good as VisualSVN Server?

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server, collabnet

the tigris website

http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#windows

has a link to another svn server, which is called CollabNet SVN Server.  Does someone use it and know it is better or as good as the VisualSVN Server?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, CollabNet has the original source code of subversion. Check this out from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CollabNet):

> In 2000, CollabNet started the open
>   source project Subversion, a version
>   control system with over 5 million
>   users.

What VisualSVN does is to package this with a small HTTP server and to add a bunch of UI to make it easier for non-advanced users (and they do it very well). In the [change log](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/) it is documented how they are incorporating -original- SVN versions, currently 1.6.1

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the biggest difference is that you have to configure the CollabNet's server package manually, while VisualSVN comes with a nice UI where you can do the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

We use CollabNet's server package where I work (I introduced version control where I work, and so far only my project uses version control).

Basically, they're the same thing.  VisualSVN comes with a module that automatically plugs into the windows network for authentication.  CollabNet's svn server has to be configured to authenticate through windows.

Since I haven't done that configuration step yet we authenticate through the .htaccess file and apache's authentication module.

Comment: I really like the "one-check" Windows authentication configuration VisualSVN has.

Answer (score 1):

CollabNet works great, but it doesn't have the visual interfaces for management that are included in VisualSVN.

If they are not important to you, and you're comfortable using standard SVN command line commands, CollabNet is a nice option.

Answer (score 0):

CollabNet released a new subversion server software:

http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/

I did not yet try it but I looks like this would beat VisualSVN Server easily...

Comment: We are currently running Subversion Edge and I am quite happy with it. Configuring SSPI requires some manual work, but the rest works very nicely out-of-the-box. Updating the installation has never been easier...

Answer (score -1):

In addition, VisualSVN doesn't support svn:// protocol which I hear is faster than http/https://. Would like someone to correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Just for reference, Subversion Edge also doesn't support svn:// protocol.